# How do i find Thevenin and Norton equivalent? [updated]

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws, thevenin, norton

I tried calculating Vth, Rth and In but i am getting stuck at the V2 source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJDpX9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can anyone explain why Vth=45?

Comment: Show your attempt.

Comment: @Chu I happened to see the earlier schematic that was posted and then deleted. (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/309003/how-do-i-find-thevenin-and-norton-equivalents) So there was a little work done, at least. Both on a transformation as well as the voltage divider. (Added recently, though.)

Comment: You've worked out that the divider node voltage should be \$9\:\textrm{V}\$. There is no current in the \$10\:\Omega\$ resistor, though. So no voltage drop across it. This should make figuring out the \$a\$ node voltage, relative to \$b\$, rather easy. Do you see?

Comment: Vth=Voc+(voltage of source)? Down on the comments we found Rth=9.6 . Which is right?

Comment: What does a "u" followed by an underscored "o" mean? What does "10" followed by an underscored "o" mean? What are these quantities or symbols?

Comment: @Andyaka this is how we write Ω in Greece (most of us). Τhe first is 4Ω

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feEpnO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Finding \$V_{TH}\$ is straightforward

\$V_X\$ voltage is equal to:

$$V_X = 18V*\frac{4Ω}{4Ω+4Ω} = 9V$$

And from KVL we find \$V_{TH}\$ :

$$V_{TH} = V_X+(4*V_X) = 9V + 36V = 45V$$

To be able to find \$R_{TH}\$ you need to solve this circuit and find \$I_{SC}\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEbQNg.png)</sup>

And if you do just that, you will find \$R_{TH} = \frac{V_{TH}}{I_{SC}} = \frac{45V}{2.25A} = 20Ω\$

Answer (score 0):

In this question since u have a dependent source so The Rth will equal Voc/Isc
So u need to find the voltage from the thevenin theorem and the current from the norton Theorem to get the Rth 
And if u change the current source to voltage then use mesh analysis because only two loops 
But it would be easier if u show ur work then I'll understand where is ur problem

Comment: Ur work has a small mistake the current source has to change to a voltage source and v=i*R so the voltage source will Equal to 40Vo then short circuit not open circuit if u r using mesh to find the current for norton

Comment: This is basically what i am trying to do. The source is voltage (i did current by mistake). So V=I*R=0.4*10=4 right?

Comment: Yes correct my mistake I thought it was 4 not 0.4 and then Vo= (4/4+4)18 and then use KVL to get the Voc but the KvL has to include the voltages for the 10 ohm and the dependent source don't avoid them

Comment: So lets say 18=4*i1+4*(i1-i2) and 36=4*(i2-i1)+10*i2. So i1=3.3 and i2=2.1 . Is this true? Wouldn't i1 be 2.25 ?

Comment: Yes 18=8i1-4i2 and 36=-4i1+14i2 can solve using the calculator or manually will get an answer of i1=4.125 and i2 3.75

Comment: And Isc=i2, Voc=36,  so Rth=9.6 ?

Comment: Yes that is the same result I got

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @ Laya The open circuit voltage is 45 V

Comment: I checked ur comment above so what u r referring to is using KVL but not considering the 10 ohm as it there is no voltage drop ?

Comment: @KostasC. Use KVL to get the Voc not immediately the dependent voltage I mentioned that in my first comments but I forgot to do the KVL and used the dependent voltages value which isn't correct

Comment: Then what is the right solution? I thought this is how i do KVL.

Comment: It's the V0 which we already got as 9 volt + the voltage for the dependent source which is 36 so that equal the 45 volt that's the VTH